# How to change the number of components in a UIPickerView?

Tags: iphone, ios, uipickerview

I have a `UITableView` for different datas. When the user select one row, then I will popup a `UIPickerView` to let the user select some values. And I have implemented the `numberOfComponentsInPickerView` DataSource method to return the number of components for different row in the `UITableView`. actually they are all 1.

But now, I will download more data from the internet and add more rows in the `UITableView`. I called `[pickerView reloadAllComponents]` after finishing the downloading. I expected the `numberOfComponentsInPickerView` will be called so I can have more components in the picker view for the new rows in `UITableView`. But it's not working.

How can I do that? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution for my problem. Instead of trying to make the UIPickerView reload and change the number of components dynamically, I use two UIPickerView, one has 1 component, and the other has two. And I will switch between these two when the user select different rows of data in the tableview.

Hope this can help if other people has similar need.

Answer (score 5):

In XCode 4.2 running on an IOS 5 device, I was able to get [pickerView reloadAllComponents] to change the number of components in a UIPickerView.

It works exactly as you originally expected it to.  Calling reloadAllComponents caused the numberOfComponentsInPickerView method to get called.

Comment: Hmmm...ran into another problem though.  Although reloadAllComponents in IOS 5 does indeed force the numberOfComponents to get recalculated, it does NOT seem to force the widthForComponent to get recalculated!